# When gcc acts on a text file, does it just see a series of machine code representations of ASCII symbols?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

In anticipation of being eviscerated by more experienced and educated individuals, I just want to apologize for any "hand-wavey" or inaccurate phrasing that my following question is riddled with.

I know a little about text files, scanners, parsers, (and compilers overall), and the C language so hopefully that is enough to get the meat of my inquiry across.

---

When I use `gcc` on my Windows 10 computer to compile a text file written in C, what does the compiler initially see in its early phases?

For example, let's say I have a text file that exclusively contains the C language keyword `for`. Nothing else is in this file. When I prompt `gcc` to act on this file, does the compiler simply see the binary code representation of the letters `f` (01100110 as its 8 bit representation), `o` (01101111), and `r` (01110010)? I imagine that there are probably other binary codes that tell the compiler "This is a text file".

So does the machine level code that the compiler acts on look something like this?

> {*binary code at beginning of file to tell compiler this is text*}_01100110_01101111_01110010_{b*inary code at end of file to tell compiler that this is the end of the file*}

where the 01100110_01101111_01110010 is the machine level representation of `for`.

Thank you!

Comment: You are right :-) Your question is a bit difficult to fathom. **Every** bit of data and code is ultimately stored as `0`s and `1`s. So it is not clear what you mean by "what the compiler sees" . Initially the `gcc` code operates on the textual representation of the source file if that is what you mean. It parses the text source, converts that to assembly and finally converts the assembly into binary (very roughly speaking).

Comment: @kaylum thanks for being gentle! I guess what I am asking can be better phrased as "what is the textual representation of the source file that the compiler acts on" in the beginning stages of the compilation. Is it, more or less, the sequence that I highlighted above?

Comment: It is. But as I said, every bit of data in computing is like that. So it depends what level of abstraction you are really thinking about. If you are talking about it running on the machine then yes it is a series of  0s and 1s. But if you are talking about the logic and code for `gcc` then no it does not operate at that level. It operates at the text level. A lower layer abstraction will convert that into binary. But I think that will still not answer you and I would suggest your question is not suitable for Stack Overflow. It might be better discuss this fact to face with someone. Good luck!

Comment: @kaylum: “Ultimately”? Ultimately, every bit of data and code is stored as a magnetic field, electric charge, pit or bump in a layer of plastic, or other arrangement of physical things. There are no zeros or ones at all. “0” and “1” are just labels we give to the physical representations we chose. There are no actual numbers there (and cannot be since a number is an abstract concept; it has no physical existence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the input

> for

in a textfile,
the compiler will first see the fact that it is called by you to work on that file.
From that it will deduce that it must be a text file with c code. Otherwise why would you ask it to process that file. So there is no "{binary code at beginning of file to tell compiler this is text}" inside the file content.

Then yes, it reads `f`, `o`, `r`.

It does so using a service/function of the operating system, which at some point also provides the information, that the last character/byte has been read. That information however is not contained inside the file content itself. The information ultimatly comes from meta data which the file system (accessed via operating system) has on the file, e.g. its length in bytes (along with others, e.g. the exact location on the medium).
So there is no "{binary code at end of file to tell compiler that this is the end of the file}" inside the file content.

The only thing which comes close to your "{binary}" info is the newline character `\n` or the pair of return and newline `\r\n`, depending on the environment. They indicate the border between two lines (can be seen as start of a newline or the end of the previous one).

I skipped a few details, like the involvement of a preprocessor, in order to focus on the idea of your question.
Strictly speaking, when the compiler (or the part of a program which does the compiling job) works, the preprocessor (or the part of the program which does the preprocessing job) has already finished.